# Get first li Simple DOM Parser

Tags: php, parsing, dom

I just try to create small simplephpdome
target is

```
<ul id=filter><li><a href="url1"></li><li><a href="url2"></li></ul>
<ul id=filter><li><a href="url3"></li><li><a href="url4"></li></ul>
```

How to get just first `li` result for every `ul`?
I have try this

```
$html = file_get_html($url);
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$first_list_links = $xpath->evaluate('//ul[@id="filter"]/li/a');

foreach($first_list_links as $links) {
    echo $dom->saveHTML($links);
}
```

but all `li` still included

Comment: in CSS there is a selector called :first-of-type , I am not sure if you can use it in your parser because I have never worked with DOM parsers before..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using the [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) :

**PHP**

```
$html = file_get_html('<ul class="filter"><li><a href="url1"></li><li><a href="url2"></li></ul><ul class="filter"><li><a href="url3"></li><li><a href="url4"></li></ul>');
$urls = [];
foreach($html->find('.filter') as $element) {
   $url = $element->firstChild()->find('a', 0)->href;
   if (!in_array($url, $urls)) {
       echo $url . "<br/>";
       $urls[] = $url;
   }
}
```

should output :

```
url1
url2
```

Comment: thanks it working foreach($html->find('ul#filter') as $element) { 
   echo $element->firstChild()->find("a", 0)->href. '<br>'; 
}

Comment: @EyangMakmur You're welcome :) can you pls valid my answer pls sir ? :)

Comment: wait sory but its why get loop twice result url1,url3,url1,url3?

Comment: I've tried it and i only got Array('url1', 'url3'); can you past your entire code pls ?

Comment: $html = file_get_html($url);
 foreach($html->find('ul#filter') as $element)  
   echo $element->firstChild()->find("a", 0)->href.'<br>'; 
 
  }

Comment: sory its from my html page there have same ul at different line, do you know how to make stop find if its have same result?